# MainActivity waits DialogFragment's arguments

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialogfragment

I have activity that shows some data based on user's choice from starting DialogFragment but is it possible to prevent creating UI on activity until user chooses some options (from spinners) from dialog and in that waiting time to show black background or something like that shown on 2nd picture :

[image: code flow]

[image: my]

[image: wanted]
<sub>(source: [deviantpics.com](http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/07/21/1F2MEh.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can control the Dim of a Dialog after creating it:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```